# Python3 How to create a function that returns a simulation of a mortgage scenario

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I need help to calculate the total cost of mortgage and the total interest incurred in the given mortgage loan duration. Basically, at the end of loan duration, the ending balance will be zero.

From the output, I am not sure of how to compute the sum of the total interest incurred and the total cost of mortgage (mortgage amount + total interest).

Furthermore, I want the beginning amount of year 1 to be the mortgage amount (i.e. 1,000,000 from the example) but the output shows (900,000)

Lastly, I need help in creating a function that computes these codes, to make it easier for testing cases. Please assist me, thank you!

```
mortgage_amount = float(input('Enter mortgage loan amount: '))
duration = int(input('Enter the number of period in years: '))
fixed_payment = float(input('Enter the fixed payment amount per period: '))
interest = float(input('Enter the annual interest rate: '))
frequency = int(input('Enter the number of times payment occur per year: '))
print('\n')

interest_converted = interest / 100 / frequency
interest_payment = interest_converted * beginning_balance
beginning_balance = mortgage_amount

for i in range(0, duration):
    
    
    interest_payment = beginning_balance * interest_converted
    interest_payment_TVOM = interest_payment * (1 + interest_converted)
    ending_balance = beginning_balance - fixed_payment 
    beginning_balance = ending_balance
    total_payment = interest_payment_TVOM + fixed_payment

    print('Year:{:1}, Beginning Balance: ${:.0f}, Interest Payment: ${:.0f}, Fixed Payment: ${:.0f}, Total Payment: ${:.0f}, Ending Balance: ${:.0f}'.format(i + 1, beginning_balance, interest_payment_TVOM, fixed_payment, total_payment, ending_balance))

print('\n')

print('total payment: ', total_payment)
print('total interest: ', interest_payment)
```

Output:

```
Enter mortgage loan amount: 1000000
Enter the number of period in years: 10
Enter the fixed payment amount per period: 100000
Enter the annual interest rate: 1.5
Enter the number of times payment occur per year: 1


Year:1, Beginning Balance: $900000, Interest Payment: $15225, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $115225, Ending Balance: $900000
Year:2, Beginning Balance: $800000, Interest Payment: $13702, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $113702, Ending Balance: $800000
Year:3, Beginning Balance: $700000, Interest Payment: $12180, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $112180, Ending Balance: $700000
Year:4, Beginning Balance: $600000, Interest Payment: $10657, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $110658, Ending Balance: $600000
Year:5, Beginning Balance: $500000, Interest Payment: $9135, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $109135, Ending Balance: $500000
Year:6, Beginning Balance: $400000, Interest Payment: $7612, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $107612, Ending Balance: $400000
Year:7, Beginning Balance: $300000, Interest Payment: $6090, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $106090, Ending Balance: $300000
Year:8, Beginning Balance: $200000, Interest Payment: $4568, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $104568, Ending Balance: $200000
Year:9, Beginning Balance: $100000, Interest Payment: $3045, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $103045, Ending Balance: $100000
Year:10, Beginning Balance: $0, Interest Payment: $1522, Fixed Payment: $100000, Total Payment: $101522, Ending Balance: $0


total payment:  101522.5
total interest:  1500.0
```

Comment: Before we jump in too far, you realize this is *not* the way mortgage payments are calculated, right?  The principal does not go down by a fixed amount year-over-year.  The payment is fixed, and in early years, more goes to interest than principal.  Getting cumulative values shouldn't be too tough.  You can start with an "accumulation" variable **outside** of your loop and then add to it during each execution of the loop.  We can build from there.

Comment: Hi @AirSquid! Thanks for your response. I do not really know how mortgages work essentially. Do you know what are the elements that I need to fix? As in the rows of beginning balance, interest payments, fixed payments, total payment and ending balance? This question was from exercise homework in class

Answer (score 1):

So you need to do a little background on "mortgage math".  There are plenty of examples if you search for "amortization calculation (or formula)" and see how the payment is calculated from (loan amount, rate, number of periods).  Then you can calculate the fixed payment.  From there, a little more work you can figure out the formula for the interest and principal components in each pay period, which you can calculate within your loop.

After you get it going.  :)  You can set up an accumulation variable outside your loop to keep track of the running totals for principal (which should add up to the loan amount at the end) and the interest.

In pseudo-code:

```
tot_payments = 0   # to gather the total principal payments
tot_interest = 0   # to gather the interest

for period in range(num_periods):
    # calculate principal and interest
    # add to the accumulations like...
    tot_payment += payment
```